# jquery div child element search

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**Html:**

```
<div id="a">
    <span></span>
    <img />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var a = $("#a").children().find("img");
```

its showing `a.length = 0`. Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#a").find("img");
```

`find` searches for descendant of the selectors, and `<img>` isn't a descendant of any of `<div id="a"`> direct childrens.

`find` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Description: Get the **descendants** of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JPw9T/)

Note that you can get the same result with more efficient selector:

```
$("#a img")...
```

`descendant` selector [docs](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/):

> Description: Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JPw9T/1/)

Comment: @gaurav. No prob. Check the update, I added extra details and best practice. Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

The **children** function gets all the child nodes of the div, and then the **find** one attempts to find descendents of those children named "img".  Obviously that does not exist.  As gdoron points out, you need to leave out the children() part.

In case you're not aware, check out the JQuery documentation, it's a really excellent reference:

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/